# Retrieve array containing name value pair from ajax request in spring mvc

Tags: java, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

I'm unable to retrieve the 'values' in my Spring Controller. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Ajax request

```
fields[fieldID] = { 'name': fieldName, 'value': fieldValue };
fieldID++;
$.ajax({ url: '/lic/register.html',
         data: { 'send': 'login-form', 'values': fields},
         type: 'get',
         complete : function(){
             alert(this.url)
         },
         success: function( output ) {
             alert("success");
         },

      });
```

Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String suckRegister(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(value="values", required=false) String[] objectValues) {
    System.out.println(objectValues.length); // returning null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems there isn't any need for 'send': 'login-form', unless another request param accepting that value in your controller

Try,

```
$.ajax({ url: '/lic/register.html',
         data: { 'values': fields},
         type: 'get',
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         complete : function(){
             alert(this.url)
         },
         success: function( output ) {
             alert("success");
         },

      });
```

And your controller should accept

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String suckRegister(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(value="values[]", required=false) Object[] objectValues) {
    System.out.println(objectValues.length); // returning null
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but still i am getting nullexception at "System.out.println(objectValues.size());" in controller.

Comment: @dimley what happens if you try the request with tool like postman

Comment: tried the url with postman and it seems ok. But getting the same error at server side. Here is my url: "http://localhost:8080/lic/register.html?values%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=Account_type&values%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=0"

Comment: can you try,

data : { 'values': JSON.stringify(fields)}

Comment: I tried that but still getting the same error. Is there any alternate way to send the name value pair from ajax to the controller?

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain what kind of error trace i should update?